# Colorama DOWN doesn't seem to work?

Tags: python-2.7, colorama

I'm attempting to use colorama to print a line that scrolls down the screen and loops back around to the top. However, I've run into a problem with the scrolling bit. It appears that `colorama.Cursor.DOWN()` and `UP` do not actually do anything. And worse, when I try to use `FORE` and `BACK` it prints a space without moving the cursor.

I'm running windows 7, using the command prompt (not IDLE), and yes, I called `colorama.init()`

Test code:

```
import colorama, sys 
colorama.init()
for _ in range(50):
    sys.stdout.write('*****')
    sys.stdout.write(colorama.Cursor.DOWN(5))
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work? it should print a line of starts, jump down five lines, then print another line of starts, 50 times. But I actually get a line of starts with no line breaks at all.

Comment: why cant you use `print`?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint You can, but you have to add a comma to the end.

Comment: Actually, it seems it moves the cursor one charecer to the write, even with the comma.